# How do I pass all parameters to each method and run each at once

Tags: java, selenium, testng

Okay so I am using a DataProvider to pass data to a single @Test method.  That data is coming from an external database.  Before my @Test method looked like this:

```
@Test(enabled = true, dataProvider = DataProviderUtils.REGRESSION, dataProviderClass = DataProviderUtils.class) 
public void use_cases(String env, String browser, String title, String id, String orderType, String productType, String isFreeShipping, String isTaxState,
                      String billingCountry, String shippingCountry, String promoType, String isPromoFree,
                      String isPromoCode, String noOfPromoCodes, String email, Object[] customSteps){



    driverUtils.setUp(browser);
    String[] testType = title.split(" ");
    switch(testType[2].trim()){
        case "Standard_Order":
            useCases.standardOrder(id, env, productType, isFreeShipping, isTaxState, billingCountry, customSteps);
            break;

        case "Warranty_Order":
            useCases.warrantyOrder(id, env, productType, isFreeShipping, isTaxState, billingCountry, customSteps);
            break;
```

That works provided there are a few tests but when it reaches 100's then I would have an extra long switch statement which is not maintainable at all.

So I've decided to use reflection to handle it so then my code becamse:

```
@Test(enabled = true, dataProvider = DataProviderUtils.REGRESSION, dataProviderClass = DataProviderUtils.class)
public void test(String env, String browser, String title, String id, String orderType, String productType, String isFreeShipping, String isTaxState,
                      String billingCountry, String shippingCountry, String promoType, String isPromoFree,
                      String isPromoCode, String noOfPromoCodes, String email, Object[] customSteps){

    driverUtils.setUp(browser);
    String[] testType = title.split(" ");

    Class[] classes = {UseCases.class};
    for(Class clazz : classes){
        Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
        for(Method method : methods){
            try {
                method = clazz.getMethod(method.getName(), new Class[]{String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, Object[].class});
                Object invoke = method.invoke(new UseCases(), id, env, productType, isFreeShipping, isTaxState, billingCountry, customSteps);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is my UseCases class:

```
public class UseCases {

OrderData orderData = new OrderData();

static String testRailURL;
static String localURL;


//New Standard Order Creation
public void standardOrder(String id, String env, String productType, String isFreeShipping, String taxState, String billingCountry, Object[] customSteps){

    testRailURL = TestRailUtil.getEnvironment(env);
    localURL = DriverUtils._targetURL;

    DriverFactory df = new DriverFactory(DriverUtils.getDriver());

    if(TestRailUtil.TEST_GET_DATA.equalsIgnoreCase("local")){
        df.navigateToURL(localURL);
    }else {
        df.navigateToURL(testRailURL);
    }
    df.loginPage.login();
    df.homePage.verifyAdminHomePageDisplay(id, customSteps);
    df.serviceHomePage.navigateToServiceHomePage();
    df.serviceHomePage.beginOrderCreation(id, productType, TestRailEnum.STANDARD_ORDER.getId(), billingCountry, customSteps);
    df.editCreatePage.verifyOrderEditPageDisplay(id, customSteps);
    df.editCreatePage.createOrder(id, productType, TestRailEnum.STANDARD_ORDER.getId(), false, isFreeShipping, taxState, customSteps);
    df.editCreatePage.review();
    df.orderConfirmChangesPage.verifyOrderConfirmChangesPageDisplay(id, customSteps);
    df.orderConfirmChangesPage.verifyConfirmChangesPageElementsDisplay(id, customSteps);
    //df.orderConfirmChangesPage.verifyTaxAndTotal(orderType, isFreeShipping);
    if (testRailURL.contains("qa") || DriverUtils._targetURL.contains("qa")){
        df.orderConfirmChangesPage.confirm();
    }
}

//New Warranty Order Creation
public void warrantyOrder(String id, String env, String productType, String isFreeShipping, String taxState, String billingCountry, Object[] customSteps){

    testRailURL = TestRailUtil.getEnvironment(env);
    localURL = DriverUtils._targetURL;

    DriverFactory df = new DriverFactory(DriverUtils.getDriver());

    if(TestRailUtil.TEST_GET_DATA.equalsIgnoreCase("local")){
        df.navigateToURL(localURL);
    }else {
        df.navigateToURL(testRailURL);
    }
    df.loginPage.login();
    df.homePage.verifyAdminHomePageDisplay(id, customSteps);
    df.serviceHomePage.navigateToServiceHomePage();
    df.serviceHomePage.beginOrderCreation(id, productType, TestRailEnum.Warranty_Order.getId(), billingCountry, customSteps);
    df.editCreatePage.verifyOrderEditPageDisplay(id, customSteps);
    df.editCreatePage.createOrder(id, productType, TestRailEnum.Warranty_Order.getId(), false, isFreeShipping, taxState, customSteps);
    df.editCreatePage.review();
    df.orderConfirmChangesPage.verifyOrderConfirmChangesPageDisplay(id, customSteps);
    df.orderConfirmChangesPage.verifyConfirmChangesPageElementsDisplay(id, customSteps);
    //df.orderConfirmChangesPage.verifyTaxAndTotal(orderType, isFreeShipping);
    if (testRailURL.contains("qa") || DriverUtils._targetURL.contains("qa")){
        df.orderConfirmChangesPage.confirm();
    }
}
```

}

The problem is I am running the tests in parallel and when I use reflection it invokes the first method 'n' number of times before it goes to the second method. So if I have two separate tests (Standard Order test and Warranty Order test) the data is being passed in from DataProvider correctly, but the data from both tests are being passed to the first method in the UseCases class because of the way the loop is structured.

My question is, is there a way to pass in the information where the data goes to the correct method and runs both at once (in parallel), instead of looping through each method and each method runs the data more than once?

Thanks

Comment: Let's name Standard Order test and Warranty Order test as scenario. Scenario may run with different parameters. 'Before' you highly flexible tests: data provider decide which scenario is executed. 'After' (with reflection) it is changed: all scenarios are executed, data provider only decide about parameters (String[] testType is ignored). What do you want: fixed scenario or data provider decide which scenarios is executed? (I'm used to fixed scenarios or at most few fixed scenario sets, solution 'before' looks a bit strange)

Comment: If I want to alter where tests get run using the 'fixed scenarios' then I have to recompile and we are using a CI process.  We have 3 separate environments before code gets pushed to production for validation.  One of the good things about the case management tool is that I can move test cases around freely without recompiling, which can have great benefits.  BUT, as you somewhat pointed out in your last sentence that you have a few fixed scenarios and I am incorporating that as well

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you typical testing pattern:

1. Scenarios, like 'Standard Order test' and 'Warranty Order test' are test methods annotated with `@Test`.
2. Data provider provides test parameters, for example `env`. There is no need for recompilation because scenarios are common for 3 environments and only runtime parameter differs.
3. You can group scenarios into test suits to get few fixed scenario sets.

I think typical pattern is simple and powerful. If it is not enough, the ask question for that.

Your first solution, with method `use_cases` which works as dispatcher looks strange to me because usually TestNG is the dispatcher. Your second solution, with reflection, looks to me, let say, very strange.